# SQL Find where a resource does not exist across multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a database containing a table with a column for a work-order number and a column for the process the work-order has to do/has done. As an example, work-order 1 might have 3 different entries, the first containing extrusion, the second entry containing sawing, and another containing shipping. Is there a way I can write a query to find all of the work-orders that are missing the sawing process?
So on a table that looks like:

| Workorder | Process |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Extrusion |
| 1 | Saw |
| 1 | Ship |
| 2 | Extrusion |
| 2 | Ship |
| 3 | Extrusion |
| 3 | Saw |
| 3 | Ship |

I would want a query that would recognize that work order 2 is missing a SAW process. I'm stuck because the only queries I can think of all involve using `WHERE PROCESS != 'SAW'`, but that would obviously just return the other processes. Not sure if this is possible with how the table was set up, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem from a tutorial or somewhere? Because I have seen it asked before on this site.

Comment: group by on Workorder and check with Having count(*) < 3, you will get all Workorder which are missing any process, but i am not sure if that's what are you asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more generic method to find what is missing.

It generates a full set of the expected data, and using `EXCEPT` operator against the existing table to reveal what is missing.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Workorder INT,  Process VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Workorder, Process) VALUES
(1, 'Extrusion'),
(1, 'Saw'),
(1, 'Ship'),
(2, 'Extrusion'),
(2, 'Ship'),
(3, 'Extrusion'),
(3, 'Saw'),
(3, 'Ship');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Workorder FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * FROM rs
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
        ('Extrusion'),
        ('Saw'),
        ('Ship')) AS t(Process)
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+---------+
| Workorder | Process |
+-----------+---------+
|         2 | Saw     |
+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a not exists clause, as follows.

```
SELECT
     WorkOrder
FROM thetablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
     SELECT
          WorkOrder
     FROM thetablename tn
     WHERE tn.Process ='Saw'
     AND tn.WorkOrder = t.WorkOrder
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a group by

```
Select workorder
From table
Group By workorder
Having count(distinct lower(process) ='saw') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to find the Workorder that is missing the full number of processes - you don't want to be hard-coding "Saw", it could be any, so just count the number of distinct processes per workorder and compare to the highest number of processes:

```
with w as (
    select workorder, Count(*) qty
    from t
    group by workorder
)
select workorder
from w
where qty < (select Max(qty) from w);
```